# I created a new twilio brand/campaign and it looks to have a number associated with it but I cannot send texts

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Recently twilio came out with the update requiring a campaign to send texts in the U.S. I did that and was approved by Twilio but I still cannot send outgoing texts from my registered number.

I keep getting exceptions for my outgoing texts. With the message `US A2P 10DLC - Message from an Unregistered Number`
[image]

I have a brand that is verified by Twilio.
[image]

If you go to the connected message service you can see that the number I am trying to send texts from is attached to the brand/campaign but I am still getting the unregistered number exceptions.
[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple messaging service by any chance? Sometimes a new messaging service is created by the campaign process, and you end trying messaging with a different messaging service.

Comment: @DipenBhikadya I'm not exactly sure how this was fixed. I put in a case to Twilio and they replied that is can take up to two weeks and then the issue was fixed.